# jquery msgbox delete gridview row before confirm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, updatepanel, updateprogress, msgbox

I want to delete rocord after confirm but When I click on the button immediately deletes record and after show confirm. here is the script;

```
function confirm() {
          var count = document.getElementById("<%=hfCount.ClientID %>").value;
          var gv = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID%>");

          var chk = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
          for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
              if (chk[i].checked) {
                  count++;
              }
          }
          if (count == 0) {

              $.msgBox(
              {
                  title: "Alert",
                  content: "Please select record!",
                  type: "info"
              })

          }
          if (count > 0) {

              $.msgBox(
              {
                  title: "Alert",
                  content: "Do you want to delete selected("+count+")records? ",
                  type: "confirm",
                  buttons: [{ value: "yes" }, { value: "no"}],
                  success: function (result) {
                      if (result == "yes") {
                          alert ("delete success");

                          });



                      }
                  }
              })
```

here asp.net code;

Comment: So, where is the confirm() function triggered in your html?

Comment: Please help help help

Comment: <asp:Button ID="selectAll" Text="Seçili Olanları Sil" runat="server" OnClientClick="confirm(); " onclick="selectAll_Click" />

Comment: What are you using for your pop up confirmation box? It almost looks like jQuery UI's Dialog